# Android webview pixels

Tags: javascript, java, android, css, webview

I have an android app with webview.
The problem is: if i put a div (width:400px) in html code webview is scaling it.
I get screen width at "java" and I'd like to set all width, height, font size in JS code.
So let one pixel in JS one pixel at webview screen too.

I try following code with my test device (800px x 480px) but the 400px width div not at left half of screen. (about 600px width at screen)

Activity code:

```
    myWebView=new WebView(this);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
try {
 myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
 myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
 }
 myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
 myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
 myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
} catch (Exception e) {
 // doesn't matter
}
```

index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body id="body" style="background: #000000;">
<div style="display:block;width:400px;height:240px;position:absolute;border:1px solid #ff0000;background:#ffff00;z-index:10000000"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android use Density Pixels(dp) instead of Pixels(px).
Use width in % in your HTML Code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id="body" style="background: #000000;">
    <div style="display:block;width:40%;height:240px;position:absolute;border:1px solid #ff0000;background:#ffff00;z-index:10000000"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think it works.

Comment: I have to specify the dimensions in pixels to make the ui accurate.

Comment: Then you have to make it responsive for best to show in webview using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This reply might be too late, sorry. What you should do (if you can not rely on %) is to report from the WebView on load (javascript) the actual dimensions to the Android class (you need to first set up an interface for this) and then scale your sizes to the real WebView dimensions:

On the Android activity (or any other class):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Set the dimensions from the webView page
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(int width, int height) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + width + "x" + height, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    }

}
```

On the WebView javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof Android !== "undefined" && Android !== null) {
        Android.showToast(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    } else {
        alert("Not viewing in webview");
    }
};
```

In my project, I didn't end up using this approach just because I realized I can do the rescaling in Javascript detecting the actual width and height inside the WebView (javascript) on window load and then do the resizing there without having to report it to the activity (java).